# R EML: system.file empty and set_methods Error in setwd(wd) : cannot change working directory

Tags: r, eml

I'm trying to create EML metadata with the `EML` package, but am failing at the `methods_file` step.

The package example suggests to add the methods like this:

```
methods_file <- system.file("examples/hf205-methods.docx", package = "EML")
methods <- set_methods(methods_file)
```

I'm doing the following:

```
library(EML)
library(emld)

setwd("C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Uni/Projects/EMS/R")
getwd() # yes it works

methods_file <- system.file("../EMS_data_prep.docx", package = "EML")
   # creates an empty "" object - I guess it should show something
   # the Word document is closed
   # I also tried using the exact path instead of the relative one

methods <- set_methods(methods_file)
Error in setwd(wd) : cannot change working directory
   # I assume this doesn't work because methods_file is empty

getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/jdemm/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgLZmp5"
   # it has now changed my working directory
```

I'm utterly bewildered by this problem. Does this mean that it doesn't like my Word document? What should `methods_file` look like?

```
Microsoft R Open 4.0.2
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I misunderstood the use of `sytem.file`, this is only used to include files provided by a package (for example as an example). This line should just be changed to the path instead:

```
methods_file <- "../EMS_data_prep.docx"
```